# Global intents that are fired for all Android notifications

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-intent

Are their any global intents that are fired for all Android notifications?

I know there are a few specific kind like `PHONE STATE` & `SMS RECEIVED`, but are there any others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no global intent that is broadcasted for every Notification.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's pretty easy to write one. Simply add a  that corresponds to every possible action, and it should do the job.